# Let the site administrator edit content at page

Tags: views, users, nodes

I'm using views (outputing fields) to display the content of a page and that's working fine for the end user (the visitors). I have 2 questions about the administration for this page.

1. Is it possible to let the administrators edit the content type(s) within the view from the page that´s being displayed? Like the way you do when you edit articles (click edit in the right corner)? Views can do that when you list content but not fields? See my screenshot where i try to explain it.

[image: See screenshot 1 here]

2.Is it possible to organize the content (and the different content types) in a structured an hierachial order that's meaningful for the site administrators? For example I would love to first list the page on level 1 and then display the different content types below the page on level 2. See my second screenshot where I try to explain this.

[image: See screenshot 2 here]

Comment: Hello, and welcome on Drupal Answers. I would rather split the question in two, as they are minimally related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is not clear what you want to edit - *content types* (page, article, blog etc.) or *nodes*? If you want to edit particular nodes in a view which outputs fields, core Contextual filters module have views implementation so you can choose `Global: Contextual links` as a field. You can even configure which links to display as contextual links.
2. Check out [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) and [Administration Views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_views) as they allow you to alter the admin interface using views.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! 

1. Ok, I've found the  'Global: Contextual links' and now I've them included in my view. (I've a own content type with 4 fields that i want editable). But they're not showing up on the page? I guess I have to output the contextual links in the custom views theme-php that I use? How can I do that? 

2. Ok, great! I will check these modules out. Thank you.

Comment: You need to add and then select those fields under the Contextual links setting. For example, add: "Edit" and "Delete" fields in view, exclude them from output and in the settings for contextual links choose those two.